# Handling folds in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, code-folding

I am coming from a VScode background , and for my recent project (on Deep Learning) I am having to manage huge code files in Spyder (Version 3), and I am not seeing any option of code folding?

I am not willing to switch to another IDE , as Spyder is very productive for my project.

Please suggest any hack to do it , if it is not there in the Spyder codebase.

Comment: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5724 supposedly going to be part of V4

Comment: Till the V4 comes , any useful trick to implement it easily

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's been raised multiple times on Github but I think the only way is to wait for the release

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can install the first beta of Spyder 4 to get code folding.

If you use Anaconda, you need to use the following commands:

`conda update anaconda`

`conda update spyder`

or if you use pip, then you need to run

`pip install -U --pre spyder`

This beta is quite stable and it has been tested for more than a year.

Comment: The syntax : $ `pip install -U -pre spyder` , replies as `no such option: -p` in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be `--pre`. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: How to handle conda environments with `spyder=4.0.0b1`?, With above update `spyder-kernels` also gets updated to v1.2.0, while the [modular approach](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach) for handling environments needs `spyder-kernels==0.*`

Answer (score 6):

Spyder 4.0.1 is released, which supports code folding.
If you are using anaconda, use

conda update --all

to get it.

Comment: I have 4.1.5 and it there is no folding in my .py files, Preferences | Editor | Show code folding is enabled. Update:  this is a known issue https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/14166

Comment: The latest Anaconda comes with 4.1.5, the fix is to move to Spyder 4.2, a pain as upgrades in Anaconda seem inevitably to be

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fold more that just a loop or a function, you can also try:

```
#%% 

Code that you want to fold

#%%
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well! This question is quite old, it did not used to work back then.